# How to retrieve a PDF using WebBrowser or WebClient in .NET?

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms

I am trying to automate the daily retrieving of a web file using .NET.

The file is a PDF located at an address similar to:

http://www.example.com/?s=doc20101022

and these are the headers of HTTP request registered for debug using IE

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS)
Vary: User-Agent,Accept-Encoding
Expires: 0
Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: public
Last-Modified: Mon, 22 Nov 2010 22:45:12 GMT
Cache-Control: private
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="doc20101022.pdf"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-Type: application/force-download
Date: Tue, 23 Nov 2010 10:41:43 GMT
X-Varnish: 2155914052
Via: 1.1 varnish
Content-Length: 6596997
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
Connection: Keep-Alive
Age: 2
```

Can you please suggest me a way to get it and save it locally using WebClient, WebBrowser or other VB.NET (Framework 4.0) components?

Answer (score 2):

Use the [DownloadFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144194.aspx) or [DownloadFileAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144196.aspx) method of [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx):

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(delegate(object source, AsyncCompletedEventArgs args) {
    // Do something when the file has been downloaded successfully.
});
wc.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("http://www.example.com/?s=doc20101022"), @"C:\Yourfile.pdf");
```

Edit: You tagged the question with c# and only mentioned .NET in the subject so I've provided you with a C# solution. If you need it in VB.NET it should be easy to port though.

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work as desired. It downloads me something but the content is an HTML page and not a PDF document. Probably is involved some redirect through http://www.example.com/?s=doc20101022

Comment: Well if the page does not redirect to the actual file you need to involve some parsing. Let me guess.. you want to download from some one click hoster? If yes give us an example link so we can have a look at it.