# Call a webapi control to return pdf, but with headers

Tags: asp.net-web-api, webclient

[How to retrieve a PDF using WebBrowser or WebClient in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255336/how-to-retrieve-a-pdf-using-webbrowser-or-webclient-in-net)

I have a similar request to the one above, But I want this to be that download window or automatically download the file and show up at the bottom of the browser.

I need it to be able to send headers in the request (self made/read headers). How can I have a redirect to a page, that will download the file and not automatically save?

SetupWebClient is me setting up the headers I need....

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc = this.SetupWebClient(wc);
wc.DownloadData(http://www.testurl.com/PdfController/GetDocumentPDF/" + customerdocument.DocumentId + "/" + customerdocument.CustomerId);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I had to do, if someone else runs into this....had to hijack the stream, and do the following:

```
.....
Stream pdfFileStream = wc.OpenRead(url)
{
    //Override stream
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=bylaws.pdf");
    pdfFileStream.CopyTo(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream);
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.SuppressContent = true;
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream.Flush();
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream.Close();
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
}
```